# Android MaterialButton Set Check in XML for DataBinding

Tags: android, android-xml, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter, materialbutton

I'm using `MaterialButton` within `MaterialButtonToggleGroup`:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    android:id="@+id/majors_toggleGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/cs_button"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"                //doesn't work
        android:text="CS" />

    ...
```

The arrtribute `android:checked` just doesn't work, I can use `setCheck()` in `Activity` or `Fragment`, but for using DataBniding I have to use the XML attribute. Any help?

Comment: can you replace it with `app:checked` and see

Comment: @Zain It doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have to use `BindingAdapter` function to achieve this functionality.

**1. Create `BindingAdapter` Function:**

```
object DataBindingUtil {
    @BindingAdapter("checkedIndexes")        //custom attribute
    @JvmStatic
    fun setChecked(toggleGroup: MaterialButtonToggleGroup, checkedIndexes: List<Int>) {
        checkedIndexes.forEach {
            (toggleGroup.getChildAt(it) as MaterialButton).isChecked = true
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Apply to `MaterialButtonToggleGroup`:**

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    android:id="@+id/majors_toggleGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:checkedIndexes="@{viewModel.majorIndexes}">    //here, multi-selection for now
```

Answer (score 1):

To set your initial state of `MaterialButton` as the checked button by default in a group of buttons, you can do that by referencing the button id in `app:checkedButton` in the `MaterialButtonToggleGroup`

So, In your code:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    android:id="@+id/majors_toggleGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:checkedButton="@+id/cs_button" 
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/cs_button"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CS" />

    ...
```

You may also check [documentation](https://material.io/develop/android/components/radiobuttons).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's kind of "hard code", not quite suitable for my case.